# What does % at the end of "version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"%" mean?

Tags: scala, sbt

I see in a `build.sbt` file:

```
organization := "wfdf23"

name := "default"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"%
```

There is a `%` at the end of the `version` line. What does it mean?

---

Update: It's generated by the [sbt np plugin](https://github.com/softprops/np), and is valid to be loaded by `sbt`

```
➜  np-test  sbt np
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/freewind/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Set current project to np-test (in build file:/private/tmp/Wfdf23/np-test/)
[info] Generated build file
[info] Generated source directories
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2014-9-19 22:05:01

➜  np-test  cat build.sbt
organization := "np-test"

name := "default"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"%                                                                                            

➜  np-test  sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/freewind/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Set current project to default (in build file:/private/tmp/Wfdf23/np-test/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.5
[info] The current project is {file:/private/tmp/Wfdf23/np-test/}np-test 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, np.Plugin, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4

➜  np-test  cat ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/np.sbt
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",
  url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(
    Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "np" % "0.2.0")
```

Comment: hmm that looks awfully like a typo to me. I am pretty sure that's not valid in an sbt build file

Comment: It's valid, because `sbt` can load it without any errors

Comment: I just tried it in one of my projects and it didn't load. which version of sbt are you using ?

Comment: It doesn't work: `version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"%
        ^
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` @Freewind: you many want to specify the steps long with versions of tools you are using. Or better yet report it to np project itself.

Comment: I just tried creating a project with np I don't get a % ...

Comment: See all my command outputs in the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `%` at the end of the last lines is the means of zsh informing you about so-called *partial lines*, i.e. lines with no `\n` at the end of line, for example when `cat`ing a file.

It appears you work under the zsh or oh-my-zsh shell (the prompt looks familiar) so the `%` in your question are the zsh/oh-my-zsh shell's thingy that don't really appear in the files inside, i.e. when you open the files you'll see there are no newlines at the end of the files in question.

p.s. You'd be surprised how my face looked when I noticed it in my terminal after a day wondering about a solution.

Comment: Think about the people who tried to reproduce the issue (!) It's a complete coincidence that I read your question, thought about it and ultimately noticed in my shell. Inconceivable, isn't it?